# Powershell script changes directory of parent powershell

Tags: powershell

When running a powershell script which changes a directory via `cd` (or `set-location`/`push-location`/etc.), the console that the script was run from also ends up in that directory.

Example:
script.ps1

```
cd c:\tmp
# do stuff
```

If I run this from `c:\users\me`, i end up in `c:\tmp`.

```
PS C:\users\me> .\script.ps1
PS C:\tmp> |
```

Now I know that I could use `push-location` and later do `pop-location`. However this wouldn't work if the script stopped somewhere in the middle (via Exit).

How can I solve this? Why doesn't the script have it's own location stack?

Comment: You could always use `Try/Catch/Finally`. Set the current directory path to a variable and then `cd c:\tmp` before the `Try`, and have the directory changed to variable in the `Finally`?

Comment: You could instead call with `powershell -File .\script.ps1`

Comment: thx @JClaspill. Finally even works with `exit`.

Comment: thx, @arco444. However this only works if the script location is known, I get a problem if it's somewhere on $env:PATH.

Comment: @IgorLankin What...? What do you mean **if the script location is known**? From your example you seem to know where it is...

Comment: @arco444: My example was made up, of course. I need this to work with scripts that are in my bin folder, which is on my %PATH%. This way I would just call "script.ps1" without knowing the full path to it. This doesn't seem to work with the -File argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use `Try/Catch/Finally`. Set the current directory path to a variable and then `cd c:\tmp` before the `Try`, and have the directory changed to variable in the `Finally`?

**Example 1**

```
$path = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
cd c:\temp
Try
{
    #Do stuff
    #exit is fine to use
    #this will output the directory it is in, just to show you it works
    Write-Host (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    #error logging
}
Finally
{
    cd $path
}
```

**Example 2** using `popd` and `pushd`

```
pushd c:\temp
Try
{
    #Do stuff
    #exit is fine to use
    #this will output the directory it is in, just to show you it works
    Write-Host (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    #error logging
}
Finally
{
    popd
}
```

I'd also recommend looking at what arco444 suggested, which is calling the powershell script via the `-File` parameter. Depending on the scenario that might work as an option.

Comment: Thank you. This solves the issue. I still think the script should have its own location stack, though.

Comment: I'd prefer `pushd c:\temp`and just `popd` in the finally block. The commands are available since PS 2.0. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849855.aspx

Comment: @IgorLankin Added the `pushd` example for any future viewers. Good stuff!